# Extending phpdocumentor2 for custom features

Tags: php, phpdoc, phpdocumentor2

i started using phpdocumentor2 for php project and want to extend it so it have custom features.

I want to make it output "Newest functions/methods/classes" under the default generated content. what my idea is when its run to be able to compare if any element in parsed file have new @version maybe or even by file change date.

Does anyone know if this is possible and how to do it with this doc generator or other?

Also does anyone know if current phpdocumentator2 support correctly @uses and if not what other workarounds there are to make it work? i need it to connect my project classes.

Comment: anyone having any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might not be exact answer you looking for.

`composer.json` - have pointed me to

https://github.com/mpociot/reflection-docblock - Project. Looks like it is used for parsing docBlocks.

See https://github.com/mpociot/reflection-docblock/blob/master/src/Mpociot/Reflection/DocBlock/Tag.php#L60

The problem is that document generation is part of original project. So you might need to also look in to https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2/tree/develop/src/Application/Renderer as well there might be some templates to add/update.